# Namespace conflicts in Silverlight app

Tags: silverlight, model-view-controller

My Application has the following structure:

- myproject (primary Silverlight project)
- myproject.Web (website for the app)
- myproject.Controls (Class library so I could do some inheritance with controls)
- myproject.Classes (Classes representing the data the controls bind to)

It seemed like a good idea having these split into projects with their own sub-namespaces, but I'm running into a lot of coupling issues and that is leading to circular dependency namespace problems.

From what little iOS development I have done, it feels kind of like I am trying to roll my own MVC solution here. What is the recommended way of going about having controls (essentially forms) backed by data in a Silverlight app?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suggest doing that split *within* the primary Silverlight application itself (a single project with multiple folders). Unless you know right now that you will have to reuse the code within the classes and controls namespaces within different Silverlight applications, I would avoid it. Silverlight is UI, anything you will want to reuse should be in the ASP.NET part of the project (logic, db access, business rules, etc).

If you take this approach, your UI won't become an albatross around your neck.

Keep your Silverlight applications thin, fast and pretty - I promise you won't regret it.

**EDIT:** The downvote made me realize I was unclear (clearer, more concise version below):

Don't split your solutions into projects based on namespaces - it leads to needless complication. Use namespaces within projects to organize code. Keep project counts to a minimum, and only split when there is a compelling need.

Good Luck!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean when you say "within the primary Silverlight application"?

Comment: Sure, use a single Silverlight project, and create namespaces within it (creating a folder does this automatically).

Comment: Okay, I think mine are in separate project folders in the overall solution's folder.

Comment: Right, and I suggest avoiding that. Namespaces != visual studio projects, but it often feels like you should have a project per namespace. It causes more problems than it solves to do that. Keep your project count to a minimum. In your case, a single web and a single Silverlight project are enough. Organize namespaces within those projects, but keep the solution organization simple. It will pay off to only create new projects when you NEED them. Splitting them out is usually anticipatory design that adds unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 1):

The projects look fine provided the namespaces and assembly names match. You can do the following:

- myproject.Classes     Can reference none
- myproject.Controls    Can reference myproject.Classes
- myproject             Can reference myproject.Controls AND myproject.Classes
- myproject.Web         Can reference myproject.Classes, but shouldn't need to

Comment: I'm using the app.xaml file in myproject to host a variable that needs to be accessible throughout the app. Can the sub-namespaces gain access to that somehow?

Comment: Not directly, but the System.Windows assembly has the `Application` class which has a static `Current` property that will get the current application. From there you can get resources: `var thing = Application.Current.Resources["MyKey"];` I would advise creating a class in your "base" project (myproject.Classes) that would hold information as you cannot guarantee that the application will have that resource.

Comment: That class would have to be a singleton right? I was kind of trying to just avoid that with using a variable declared in the App.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions on this problem. I selected Audie's answer as the solution because it resolved the problem with including namespaces through projects.